# How to set the metadata type according to the file format?

Tags: dspace

Example:

if bitstream format =

```
   .mp4
   .mpeg
   .avi
```

set dc.type = **video**

if bitstream format =

```
   .pdf
   .text
   .doc
```

set dc.type = **text**

if bitstream format =

```
   .png
   .jpeg
   .gif
```

set dc.type = **image**

etc...

It is possible do this for internal collections and collections collected externally via harvest?

Via database or altering source-code?

Answer (score 3):

I would write a [curation task](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Curation+System) for this, and run it periodically over all items in the harvested collection. In fact I have one [right here](https://github.com/lconz-irr/Curation-Tasks/blob/master/src/main/java/nz/ac/lconz/irr/curate/task/AnnotateWithBitstreamFormats.java) that does almost what you need -- it populates dc.format.mimetype with the mime types of all ORIGINAL bitstreams in the item.

Terry's suggestion of customising the submission process / the collection template mechanism may not work -- I'm not sure that harvested items go through either of these two processes.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fix your existing records, you could run a SQL query to find the item_id for items that need modification.  Once you have that list of ids, you can use the following tool to add a dc.type to your items:

https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Batch+Metadata+Editing

I do not believe that DSpace is able to assign a dc.type based on the bitstream uploaded. You would need to code that yourself.

Looking at the Submission process documentation, you can configure a submission workflow collection by collection: https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/Submission+User+Interface#SubmissionUserInterface-AssigningacustomSubmissionProcesstoaCollection

It is possible to define a default template for a collection.  New items submitted to that collection will receive template values by default.